# How do I define a colorspace and set it on images in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, color-space

An application that I work on programmatically generates a PDF. I was asked to add the ability to set the colorspace of the images, which should all be the same. Currently, my code generates the colorspace as the following:

```
3 0 obj
<<
/N 3
/Alternate /DeviceRGB
/Length 284
/Filter [/FlateDecode]
>>
stream
8c``2ptqre``ÈÍ+)
rwRˆˆŒR`¿ÀÀÁÀÍ Ì`Ì`˜\\ààÃ yùy© |»ÆÀ¢/ë‚ÌÂ”Ç¸’ŠJ€ô 6JI-Nf``4 ²³ËK
€âŒs€l‘¤l0{ˆ]äd²ùÒ!ì+ v„ýÄ.zÈþRŸf3q€Í°e@ì’Ô
½Îù•E™é%
F
Ž)ùI©
Á•Å%©¹Å
žyÉùEùE‰%©)@µ÷ D!(Ä4---4Iô7A Šës 8|ÅÎ Ä ¹´¨Êdd2&ÌG˜1G‚Á)Ë„˜I/Ãþ©15C}†}s Ã¯Po
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj
[/ICCBased 3 0 R]
endobj
```

This works, in and of that the PDF will load. However, when I try to set that colorspace on an image, such as the following:

```
23 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject 
/Subtype /Image 
/Name /I5 
/Length 2995953 
/Width 3675 
/Height 3675 
/Filter /DCTDecode 
/ColorSpace 4 0 R
/BitsPerComponent 8
>>
stream
```

*Image data not included here for brevity*

```
endstream
endobj
```

This looks valid based on scanning another PDF with an image. If I don't try to replace the Colorspace, but instead use "/Colorspace /DeviceRGB", the PDF loads fine.

I know I'm probably missing something important here, but I can't figure out what.

[ICC profile being used](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5xm6tcvb98vngcw/AdobeRGB1998.icc?dl=0)

[Bad PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9078dsmpl5wolb5/Bad%20PDF.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Are you confident with using special ASCII characters in what clearly should be pure binary data? Or is this just a simulated view and the actual data *is* the correct binary form of a compressed color space?

Comment: The actual data is indeed the compressed color space. If it would make things less confusing, I can replace that with a note that there's data not shown, as I did with the image data.

Comment: Are you confident with the data in the ICC stream data? (correctly read, encoded and that the source ICC is of type RGB)

Comment: @dwarring Not 100%. It's all a valid ICC profile, which I can plug into ImageMagick for converting images, but I haven't found any guidance on whether the whole thing gets dumped into the PDF, or if I either need to only use part of it, or convert it somehow. I do not get an error on opening the PDF until I assign the color profile.

Comment: Are you able to add links to sample input ICC and output PDF (e.g. using Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive,  Mediafire or whatever)

Comment: @dwarring: I have added links.

Comment: Not sure if it explains this problem, but xref is missing one entry. for `4 0 R`. Have manually added as follows: `xref
0 26
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000201 00000 n 
0000000253 00000 n 
0000000638 00000 n % <-- here
0000000671 00000 n 
0000000764 00000 n 
0000000928 00000 n ...`

Comment: @dwarring: Bingo. I had left off a call in the code. I have fixed that and it works. Thank you.

Comment: @dwarring: If you want to write that up as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the cross reference index, which was missing the entry for `4 0 R` the `[/ICCBased 3 0 R]` object.

I noticed the problem when opening the PDF with xpdf, which gave the error: `Internal Error: xref num 25 not found but needed, try to reconstruct`.

From there, I manually cross-checked the cross reference table against the actual objects using a text editor to locate the missing object.

The xref table needed a couple of small edits, as follows:

`xref
0 26                 %% <-- was 0 25
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000201 00000 n 
0000000253 00000 n 
0000000638 00000 n   %% <-- added this line
0000000671 00000 n 
0000000764 00000 n 
0000000928 00000 n 
0000001031 00000 n 
0000001195 00000 n 
0000001298 00000 n 
0000001464 00000 n 
0000001568 00000 n 
0000001734 00000 n 
0000001838 00000 n 
0000002004 00000 n 
0000002108 00000 n 
0000002274 00000 n 
0000002378 00000 n 
0008538650 00000 n 
0012148952 00000 n 
0020386142 00000 n 
0025352962 00000 n 
0027568145 00000 n 
0030564286 00000 n 
0030564334 00000 n 
trailer`

PDF then opened and displayed normally, using xpdf.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a valid Image XObject in a PDF that is currently being represented in a certain ColorSpace, e.g. DeviceCMYK.  If you would like to change that image to use a different ColorSpace, e.g. DeviceRGB (I'll put aside the reason for why you are doing this) then normally you have to transform the image data from one to the other.

Otherwise if you just change the colorspace being referenced you run the risk of the image not being shown as you would expect (e.g. looking inverted or colors mixed up).  It's possible you have a case where the image data doesn't appear changed however this is going to be a very fragile approach if you aren't actually changing the image data properly.

You may get a more helpful answer if you mention what API you are using for instance to work with the PDF.

Comment: The image has already been outputted in the correct colorspace. We just want to store that colorspace in the PDF so that the printer can use it to tune the final product. As for the API, it's a homemade one that just writes out the tags.